# Different outputs in Xcode and terminal

Tags: c, terminal

This code gives an output:

in Xcode console: for `2015-12-23` output `date: Wed 2015-12-23`

on linux terminal: for `2015-12-23` output `2015-08-26` (before 2015 it's just a space)

Can anybody tell me how it's possible? I tried puts() method when printing a date, but it didn't help too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

// Functions declaration
int StringLength(char *string);
bool IsDate (char myString[100], int length);
bool IsNumber (char myString[100], int length);
bool IsPrime (char myString[100]);
bool IsPalindrome (char myString[100], int length);

// Global variables declaration
int i;
int code;

bool tmp = true;
bool date = true;

char buffer[3];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char unknownString[100];
    printf("Insert a date string: ");
    code = scanf("%100s", unknownString);

    while (code == 1) {

        date = IsDate(unknownString, strlen(unknownString));
        printf("date: %s %s\n", buffer, unknownString);

        printf("Insert a date string: ");
        code = scanf("%100s", unknownString);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool IsDate (char myString[100], int length) {

    tmp = true;
    struct tm timeString;

    // Only unknownString == 10 could be date because of the format DDDD-DD-DD which has 10 characters
    if (length == 10) {
        // Without this condition, IsDate would be true with format 1234x56x78
        if (myString[4] == '-' && myString[7] == '-') {

            timeString.tm_year = atoi(myString) - 1900;
            timeString.tm_mon = atoi(&myString[5]) - 1;
            timeString.tm_mday = atoi(&myString[8]);
            timeString.tm_hour = 0;
            timeString.tm_min = 0;
            timeString.tm_sec = 1;
            timeString.tm_isdst = 0;

            if (mktime(&timeString) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to make time.\nError in IsDate function.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else {
                strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &timeString);
            }
        }
        else {
            tmp = false;
        }
    }
    // If length is different than 10
    else {
        tmp = false;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Why %99s? Where is difference?

Comment: Isn't `char buffer[3];` too small for storng `dd hh:mm:ss` by `strftime`?

Comment: You need to reserve space for th NUL-terminator at the end of the string. `99` tells `scanf` to read a maximum of 99 characters and then append a `\0` at the end of the string.

Comment: But I need to read 100 characters, so [0]-[99] is some char and [100] is '\0'

Comment: If so, use a buffer of size 101, not 100. "_[100] is '\0'_" -- The `\0` is written in an invalid memory location just after the array if the size of the buffer used is 100. So use a buffer of size 101 to overcome this problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: You should never use `i` as the name of a global variable.  You should avoid global variables when possible.  `tmp` should be local to `IsDate()`.  `buffer` should be local to `main()` and passed (along with its size, which should be a lot bigger) to `IsDate()`; `date` and `code` should be local to `main()`.  The irrelevant function declarations should have been omitted.

Comment: Also, a good technique is to print the input that the program just read.  For example, after reading the date, use: `printf("Input: [[%s]]\n", unknownString);` to echo the value.  The double square brackets serve to delimit the string; you can spot all sorts of things if they're present.  There shouldn't be any leading spaces, for example — `%s` skips those. Sometimes, and this might be one of those times, you should print the length too: `printf("Input (%zu): [[%s]]\n", strlen(unknownString), unknownString);`. This may help you understand why it goes haywire. Also test input function results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer `buffer` is too short for a locale’s appropriate date and time representation. Make this buffer at least 32 bytes.

```
char buffer[32];
```

I believe you found a bug in Xcode, this code:

```
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &timeString);
```

Should never produce `Wed` in `buffer`.  It should either produce nothing as it does in terminal or clip the name to 2 characters `We`. If you are only interested in the weekday abbreviation, make the buffer at least 4 bytes and use format `"%a"`.